# How to install Maven in Windows?

Tags: java, apache, maven

Hello I am just download maven binaries and after set all the environment variable, I am running `mvn -version` cmd and get this exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access field org.codehaus.plexus.util.Os.OS_NAME from class
>   org.apache.maven.cli.CLIReportingUtils 
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.CLIReportingUtils.showVersion(CLIReportingUtils.java:71)
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.cli(MavenCli.java:423)
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:277)
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Comment: Check this: [Maven on Windows](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html)

Comment: What versions of maven and jdk are you using?

Answer (score 14):

1. Download Maven [at here](http://mirror.downloadvn.com/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip).
2. Unzip, for example: `C:\tools\`
3. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `systempropertiesadvanced`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Set environment: `MAVEN_HOME` = `C:\tools`

Add to `PATH` environment variable: `;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`

5. Close all
6. Call `cmd`, run command:

   mvn -v

Comment: Let's clean everything, then install everything from scratch.

Comment: Remove `MAVEN_HOME` really not needed only the bin folder into PATH that's it. And of course JAVA_HOME setting to JDK...and than `mvn --version`...BTW: Use for download this: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @DoNhuVy, I think there is type of ENV variable, it should be `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`

Answer (score 9):

1. Open PowerShell or terminal and run `java -version` to make sure Java is installed

[image: Java is installed]

2. Go to Apache Maven's [download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and, if you're using Maven just as a tool, download the "Binary zip archive" from the link

[image: Apache Maven download page]

3. Place the downloaded file in the folder where you have all your Java related things (in my case, `C:\Program Files\Java`)

[image: Java folder]

4. Right click in that file and "Extract here". Then, delete the .zip file.

[image: Extract Maven binary zip]

if we open that new folder we should have something like

[image: Maven Windows folder]

5. Go to advanced system settings (by searching for that term or right clicking in "This PC" > Properties) and "Environment variables".

[image: View advanced properties]

6. Define a new System Environment Variable by clicking New and

[image: M2_HOME Environment Variable]

```
Variable Name: M2_HOME

VARIABLE VALUE: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.6.3
```

7. Append the bin subdirectory of the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.6.3` into the PATH variable

[image: Add Maven to Path]

8. Restart your computer and then run `mvn --version`.

[image: Maven installed in Windows 10]

That's it, you have now Maven installed in Windows 10.

Comment: Can you clarify point 7? What do you mean append? Why not creating directly the variable with the correct path in point 6?

Comment: @alexlomba87 you can do that too yes!

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 11 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add system variable JAVA_HOME (with address JDK) and M2_HOME with route directory maven.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

```
1. Download Maven from <https://maven.apache.org/>  
2. Unzip anywhere on your system
3. Go to Control pannel on your windows machine and edit the environmentalvariable(PATH = "your maven path/bin")  
4. Save   
5. Go to command prompt and run the command mvn -version
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use M2_HOME property in environment variable - system property and configure the maven bin folder as value.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/ check this out..you need to have Java & you have to add maven details in environment variables path.

Comment: open cmd prompt and type "mvn -version".You will get maven details.If you get that then maven home is set.