# testing my code with junit tester did not work i get errors

Tags: java, testing, visual-studio-code, junit

hi there I am trying to test my code java code with JUnit test case 
 but there is a problem with the tester I don't know what it is, happy to get from your review and guides

here is the code>>

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class Ex2_Test {
static double[] po1={2,0,3, -1,0}, 
        po2 = {0.1,0,1, 0.1,3};
static final double EPS = 0.0001;

@Test
void testF() {
    double fx0 = Ex2.f(po1, 0);
    double fx1 = Ex2.f(po1, 1);
    double fx2 = Ex2.f(po1, 2);
    assertEquals()
    assertEquals(fx0,2);
    assertEquals(fx1,4);
    assertEquals(fx2,6);
}



@Test
void testRoot() {
    double x12 = Ex2.root(po1, 0, 10, EPS);
    assertEquals(x12, 3.1958, 0.001);
}

@Test
void testDerivativeArrayDoubleArray() {
    double[] p = {1,2,3}; // 3X^2+2x+1
    double[] dp1 = {2,6}; // 6x+2
    double[] dp2 = Ex2.derivative(p);
    assertEquals(dp1[0], dp2[0],EPS);
    assertEquals(dp1[1], dp2[1],EPS);
    assertEquals(dp1.length, dp2.length);
}
}
```

and here is the errors messages>>

The method assertEquals() is undefined for the type Ex2_Test
The import org.junit cannot be resolved

The method assertEquals(double, int) is undefined for the type Ex2_Test

The method assertEquals(double, int) is undefined for the type Ex2_Test

Test cannot be resolved to a type

Test cannot be resolved to a type

The method assertEquals(double, double, double) is undefined for the type Ex2_Test

The method assertEquals(int, int) is undefined for the type Ex2_Test

The method assertEquals(double, double, double) is undefined for the type Ex2_Test

please check the image here>>

[image: here is the tester]

Comment: Please post the code and the errors as text, not as image.

Comment: Could you please add some information about how you build/run your project. Do you use Maven for dependencies or do you import them through your IDE?

Comment: You need to include / import JUnit as a dependency in your project.

Comment: check now i have updated it @Turing85

Comment: can you guide me how? @stridecolossus
i have added this extension "Java Test Runner"
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test

Comment: @loaishark Never used VS for Java (didn't realise you could tbh) but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674827/junit-in-visual-studio-code) helps?

Comment: i am using the "Java Test Runner" extension to test my code here is the link>>
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test @olovholm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674827/junit-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: i am getting this error on the import >The import org.junit cannot be resolvedJava(268435846) @Polygnome

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [JUnit.jar](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:junit%20AND%20a:junit) and [add it to referenced library](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar);
2. Add the following import sentences;

   ```
    import org.junit.Test;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
   ```

About testing, you can refer to [Testing Java with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing).

Comment: @loai shark, does my answer solve your question?

Comment: check this image >>https://prnt.sc/w3g6ei  it is testing the function sum return x+y here but there is an error here are the tester result >> https://prnt.sc/w3g7q5

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you added package the `jUnit.jar` or `testNG.rar`
2. Import sentences:
   `import org.junit.Test; import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

Comment: check this image >>https://prnt.sc/w3g6ei  it is testing the function sum return x+y here but there is an error here are the tester result >> https://prnt.sc/w3g7q5