# Maven ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(

Tags: node.js, maven

I have installed JDK and set up the home variable:

```
C:\Workspace\ProjectFolder>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6
```

Then i have done:

```
npm install maven -g
```

Info about the NODE:

```
C:\Workspace\ProjectFolder>node --version
v10.16.3
```

Okay, lets see the info about MAVEN:

```
C:\Workspace\ProjectFolder>mvn --version
fs.js:136
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at makeCallback (fs.js:136:11)
    at Object.mkdir (fs.js:726:14)
    at Object.target.init (C:\Users\MyUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mvn\target.js:25:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mvn\target.js:39:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like a permission problem. There is a call `fs.accessSync(target.home, fs.F_OK)` which fails. Could you check if the user which runs node has access to the `/.maven` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The `npm` package you've installed is [`mvn`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mvn), not [`maven`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maven).)

Because the `.maven` directory doesn't existing, it's attempting to create it with this line:

> fs.mkdir(target.home);

However, it's calling `mkdir` without a callback. Since Node 10, that's an error. You'll need to use an earlier Node, or fix [the code](https://github.com/pierreneter-repositories/maven-cli/blob/master/target.js) to pass a callback. See [how to fix this error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150956/how-to-fix-this-error-typeerror-err-invalid-callback-callback-must-be-a-funct) for an equivalent change.

If you're trying to use Maven, simply [install it directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549614/how-to-install-maven-in-windows), rather than using a Node wrapper.

Comment: I tried installing maven and I tried running mvn. I still see the same error. [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function.   at Object.mkdir (fs.js:956:14)

Comment: Should I be downgrading node? is node 14 faulty?

Comment: After installing maven directly, you'll need to `npm uninstall mvn` before you can use the `mvn` command.